# How to intentionally freeze my screen?

Tags: windows-7, browser, freeze

I'm looking for a workaround to stop elements from blinking in an in-browser presentation that I have to watch.

I can't just disable scripts without breaking the whole thing.

I've given those responsible feedback, but I don't think they'll change it very fast and I can't wait longer than a few weeks.

My current workaround is to paste a screenshot of each slide into MS Paint to read the words without those annoying blinking icons. I was hoping for something less cumbersome.

**Does anyone know a way to freeze the screen, fast to do and undo?**

"Freeze" in this context means "not moving *before* I do something", it does not need to be unresponsive to input and I do need a quick way to turn it off.

I have two monitors, so it could be a program I command in one screen to freeze the other.

Yes, it does remind me of the 90's.

Comment: The presentation has blinking elements or you have scripts installed that makes it blink? Or is it a kind of tutorial that "takes control" and ask you to do something?

Comment: @laurent: The presentation has blinking elements. I mentioned "scripts" because I don't know whether the presentation is Flash or Javascript or something specific of Microsoft Sharepoint where the training platform is built on, all I know is it's in-browser.

Comment: FYI, that's very likely "animation", which can be disabled in your browser.  i.e. Tools > Options > Advanced tab. Unfortunately, you can't stop the animation if it's Flash, without it appearing blank, unless it offers a "pause" button (unlikely).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Windows 7's in-built Snipping Tool, much faster than what you're currently doing.

- Snip
- View snip in window it opens
- Close window when done, or hit "new" to snip again.

[image: Snippity-doo]

Comment: Microsoft OneNote, now free also makes it quick to grab screen shots and place them in a notebook for easy reading. Windows key + N to open send to OneNote, then press S to do a screen clipping. It also freezes the screen while you select a clipping region.